when an message match a filter how can i look back 10s before that message arrive and return all message that came before
I'm working with PySpark Streaming and need to implement a feature where, when a message matches a certain filter condition, I can look back 10 seconds before that message arrived and return all messages that came before it. Here are the details:
Problem
When a message matches a filter, I want to retrieve all messages from 10 seconds before the matching message arrived.
Context
Input Source: Kafka stream - JSON message
Filter Condition: A massage match inner join conditions of a postgresql table
Processing Framework: PySpark Streaming
From what I understand, window functions in PySpark Streaming only work after a message matches the condition. I currently can’t find a way to look up messages that happened before the matching message. To address this, I currently use .foreachBatch() on the matching messages to load previous messages stored in my Hadoop data lake and filter them using the timestamp column. However, this approach is very slow due to extensive filtering and reading from disk. Is there a way to solve this problem better
Here's a simplified version of my current code:
def process(self, batch_df: DataFrame, batch_id):
   # Perform the join and filter
   batch_df = (
       batch_df.alias("A")
       .join(
           F.broadcast(self.data),
           on=(F.col("event.Id") == F.col("A.Id")),
           how="left",
       )
       .filter(
           (F.col("A.time") >= (F.col("event.time") - F.expr("INTERVAL 10 SECONDS")))
           & (F.col("A.time") <= F.col("event.time"))
       )
   )




def run(self):
   stream_df = self.kafka_to_sparkstream(
       topic=KAFKA_TOPIC,
       bootstrap_server=KAFKA_SERVER,
       startingOffsets="latest",
   )
   self.data = (
       self.spark.read.format("parquet").load(f"{self.HADOOP_PATH}").alias("event")
   )


   parsed_df = stream_df.selectExpr(
       "CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)"
   ).withColumn("parsed_value", from_json(F.col("value").cast("string"), CREATE_MODEL))


   stream_df = parsed_df.select("key", "parsed_value.*")


   stream = (
       stream_df.writeStream.foreachBatch(self.process).outputMode("append").start()
   )
   stream.awaitTermination()


